# Getting string from other then default language

Tags: android, locale

I am having a problem in accessing Locale string in android.
 **The requirement is:-**

I have one string in *english*(`values/string.xml`) as well as in *korean*(`values-ko/string.xml`). Now i want to show my string in both languages in a single activity.

I don't want to change phone Locale or call `Locale.setDefault("ko")`

I am trying to call following line but it is not working for me.

`getString(R.string.mystring, Locale.KOREAN); //(My default language is English)`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

try

> getResources().getString(R.string.mystring,
>   Locale.KOREAN);

Comment: This does not work because [`getString(int id, Object... formatArgs)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getString%28int,%20java.lang.Object...%29) works like [`String.format(String format, Object... args)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)